# How can I set the style of a font in an Android custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This code was suggested to me:

For Android:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace FontRenderer.Droid
{
    public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        public CustomLabelRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            int fontFamilyResId;

            switch (Element.FontFamilyType)
            {
                case FontFamilyType.Light:
                    fontFamilyResId = Resource.Style.FontRobotoLight;
                    break;
                case FontFamilyType.Regular:
                    fontFamilyResId = Resource.Style.FontRobotoRegular;
                    break;
                case FontFamilyType.Medium:
                    fontFamilyResId = Resource.Style.FontRobotoMedium;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }


            Control.SetTextAppearance(fontFamilyResId);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, for Android you'll need 2 more styles (for the light & regular families). In `styles.xml` add these 2 styles:

```xml
<style name="FontRobotoLight">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<style name="FontRobotoRegular">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

What I would like to know is.  How can I do this without needing to resort to creating XAML styles and for these:

Is there a way that I could code this into the custom renderer.  So all I would need to do is specify

FontFamilyType="san-serif-light"

Answer (score 0):

If you put the font in the assest folder, you can set the font like following custom renderer code. `TypefaceStyle` provide `Normal`, `Bold`,`Italic` and `BoldItalic` style.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(MyCustomLabel))]
namespace App6.Droid
{
    class MyCustomLabel : LabelRenderer
    {
        public MyCustomLabel(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Typeface tf=Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "Modak-Regular.ttf");
            Control.SetTypeface(tf,TypefaceStyle.Bold);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

====update=======

If you want to `sans-serif` font, you can create a `Typeface`, add a attribute `Typeface.SansSerif` like following code.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(MyCustomLabel))]
namespace App6.Droid
{
    class MyCustomLabel : LabelRenderer
    {
        public MyCustomLabel(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

           Typeface tf=Typeface.Create(Typeface.SansSerif, TypefaceStyle.Bold);             
           Control.SetTypeface(tf,TypefaceStyle.Bold);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, You mention putting the font in the assets folder.  However Android already comes with many system fonts so I would just like to use the ones that match Android.

Comment: All I need is to find some way to access the font here:

fontFamilyResId = <I need something here>

Comment: Do you want to use font that comes from native android system? like this ways `Typeface tf=Typeface.Create(Typeface.SansSerif, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
            Control.SetTypeface(tf,TypefaceStyle.Normal);`

Comment: Yes I do,  what I am wondering, is how to do this in the Android custom renderer.

Comment: Thanks,  I will check your solution soon

Comment: It might be a couple of days as I have someone helping me on this and they have a busy workload.  However we will look into your answer and update.  Thank you

Comment: I will do that Leon.  Still in progress with lots of other issues to look into first. Thanks.